# How to create an empty field if the field doesn't exist in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I have a document that is created on weekly bases (`field delimeter` hold date) for each user's week.
Every time the user session expires I check to see if the user has a document for that particular week (so that all updates don't fail)

I am trying to avoid 2 fetches: `1)` a fetch to check if the document exists, `2)` create another query that creates or not that document depending on whether it exists already

I was wondering if there is such a function within `mongo`... Create if doesn't exist otherwise do nothing.

Currently, `upsert` `inserts` if it is not there or `updates` if it is there. Thus, is not a valid solution. I need  `if ( !exist){ update/insert ) else { do nothing }`

```
public function createUserSocialWallForUser( MongoId $userMongoID, $delimeter ) {
        $db = $this->db()->socialWall;

        $where = array( 'userId' =>  $userMongoID, 
                        'delimeter' => $delimeter
                      );
        $data = array(  'userId' =>  $userMongoID, 'delimeter' => $delimeter, 'event' => array() );
        $option = array ('upsert' => true);
        $db->update( $where, $data, $option); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like a perfect fit for [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert):

```
$data = array(
    '$setOnInsert' => array(
        'userId' =>  $userMongoID, 
        'delimeter' => $delimeter, 
        'event' => array()
    )
);
```

This way the `update` only sets the values if the upsert needs to do an insert (the not-exists case).

Note that this requires at least v2.4 of MongoDB.